# Ansible tower API: pass inventory_name for a job in a POST payload

Tags: ansible-tower

Please tell me how to specify the **inventory name** instead of **id** when running the template via Tower API?

Work:

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer aDFNLAKJDFLKXZDnbmz" -d '{"extra_vars":{"app":"pypypy","operation":"show"},"inventory_id":"123"}' https://localhost/api/v2/job_templates/200/launch/
```

Not work:

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer aDFNLAKJDFLKXZDnbmz" -d '{"extra_vars":{"app":"pypypy","operation":"show"},"inventory":"inventory_name"}' https://localhost/api/v2/job_templates/200/launch/
```

Error:

```
{
  "inventory": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
  ]
}
```